# Received trailing metadata size exceeds limit with .net core client . (Problem with GRPC)

Tags: c#, .net-core, dgraph

I am new in Dgraph and i’m using .NET Core C# Client (https://github.com/MichaelJCompton/Dgraph-dotnet 1) to connect Dgraph Server, query and mutation data.

**I’m facing this problem:**

```
{
  ExceptionalError with Message='Status(StatusCode=ResourceExhausted,  
  Detail="received trailing metadata size exceeds limit")',  
  Exception='Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=ResourceExhausted, Detail="received trailing metadata size exceeds limit") at  
  DgraphDotNet.GRPCConnection.Query(Request req) at  
  DgraphDotNet.DgraphClient.Query(Request req) at  
  DgraphDotNet.Transactions.Transaction.QueryWithVars(String queryString, Dictionary`2 varMap)'
}
```

**Grpc option**

```cs
var server = "xxxxx";
       CurrentClient.Connect(server, ChannelCredentials.Insecure, new[]{
        new ChannelOption(ChannelOptions.MaxSendMessageLength ,2147483647),
        new ChannelOption(ChannelOptions.MaxReceiveMessageLength , 2147483647)
  });
```

**Program.cs**

```
services.AddGrpc().AddServiceOptions<DgraphDotNet.IDgraphClient>(options => {
       options.EnableDetailedErrors = true;
       options.ReceiveMaxMessageSize = 2147483647;
       options.SendMaxMessageSize = 2147483647;
    });
```

But still facing with this problem.
Additional:
I debug to final GRPC call

```cs
CallInvoker.AsyncUnaryCall(__Method_Query, null, options, request);
```

and see the parameters like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/czAgN.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyQd7.png